# Given pdf of $I$ and $R$ (both $I$ and $R$ are independent RV's), how to find pdf of $W =I^2\cdot R$?

Tags: self-study, independence, density-function

The title defines the question. May be the concept would do...like how to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a homework exercise so I have added a tag. The exercise is simple though, first find the pdf of $I^2$ then the pdf of the product (try to do it yourself, what are the difficulties solving the exercise?). By the way solution could be found in H.Hsu. nice book for self-study http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Probability-Variables-Processes/dp/0070306443

Comment: @Dmitrij @H_S I found the question makes sence. Many other people that are not student of Dmitrij may encounter that problem. It is certainly not an advanced research question but I found this is a very good question for this site.

Comment: if $I$ and $R$ are independent so are the functions of $I$ and $R$, therefore $I^2$ and $R$ are independent too (hope you do not mix it with correlation). So you have that $f_{IR}=f_I\cdot f_R$ from the original independence of $I$ and $R$. What you need to add is a specific region of integration for the event $Z=I^2R$. Alternatively you may go for two steps, calculate $I^2$ from example 4.6 in Hsu for the 1st one, and after go for 4.21 (and look for 4.29 for a more general example of 3 independent r.v.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the pdf of $X+Y$ is given by a convolution.

You can generalize the idea of a **convolution to another group** than $(+,\mathbb{R})$ and the idea that pdf of $X\cdot Y$ (where $\cdot$ is the operation of the group) is given by the convolution is still valid. For the convolution on group see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolutions_on_groups).

For the group of multiplication $(\cdot,\mathbb{R}_+)$, the (left)-haar measure is $dt/t$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Examples)), and this gives (if $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are densities of $X$ and $Y$):

$f_{X\cdot Y}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f_X(t)f_Y(z/t)dt/t$

the density of the product $X\cdot Y$. It is straigthforward to derive the density of $I^2\cdot R$ from that.

Comment: it would be interesting to know what in particular causes difficulties to the author, since this one is really a standard pdf computation example I did with my students during random processes practice.

Comment: @Dmitrij yes but I gues I am not the one to be asked this. I gave the general idea and try to point out to @H_S that this is connected to computing the sum of random variable and that it can be generalized to other group. I gave the formulas and link to the details. I guess 90% of the good question of this site could be asked to student and it should not stop us to try to answer and try to give a point of view that can help them to reach a better understanding of the problem they are facing. I think this Q is way way more interesting than "what is standard deviation".

Comment: I agree with you and will give (+1) for this general idea and links, I hope the author will solve by himself starting from denoting $Z = I^2$, then cdf of $F_Z(z)=P\{Z\leq z\} = P\{-\sqrt{z} \leq I \leq \sqrt{z}\} = ...$ for $z > 0$ and, and $0$ for $z \leq 0$. For the product of 2 independent RV  you gave the crucial hint (but, @robin, it is $|t|$ in denominator). So @H_S, I hope to see yours complete solution here for +1 from me too.

Comment: @Dmitrij thanks for the complement. I use the notation $\mathbb{R}_+$ for positive real otherwise you are right that there should be absolute values

Comment: +1 for idea of using groups. It stil seems a bit complicated, since it requires some comfortability in algebraic methods, when Dmitrij's idea really is more elementary. On the other hand this gives a deeper understanding of the topic. I also corrected some small typos and changed formatting, I hope you do not mind.